# What addon axios have that RTK query fetchBaseQuery util is missing?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

In the documentation of the RTK query, this is the introduction that is provided to the `fetchBaseQuery` util:

> This is a very small wrapper around `fetch` that aims to simplify requests. It is not a full-blown replacement for `axios`, `superagent`, or any other more heavy-weight library, but it will cover the large majority of your needs.

OK, I get that fetchBaseQuery isn't perfect, but when should I use fetchBaseQuery over `axios` or `superagent`?

What are the tradeoffs?

Comment: http interceptors ?

Comment: It is very simple to achieve [How can we intercept APIs using RTK-query createApi ?](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/1955)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`fetchBaseQuery` pretty much supports everything that `fetch` supports (since it only calls `fetch`) - which is the modern browser api for interaction with remote data sources. To my knowledge, there is at this point only one feature that `fetch` does not support, but which is supported by the older `XMLHttpRequest` (which is uses by axios) does support: file upload progress. But since RTK Query itself only tracks the "started" and "finished" state of a query, you would not be using that with RTK Query in the first place.

So, nothing really comes to mind.

You'd really just add 6kb extra to add a tool because you're used to it. There isn't a lot of a reason to use `axios` nowadays.

**See more:**

- [How can we intercept APIs using RTK-query createApi ?](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/1955)